# Symfony2: Unable to use DoctrineExtensions Mysql Year function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have so far been unsuccessful in implementing the beberlei DoctrineExtensions.  I need the MySQL Year() function.  Error is:

> Expected known function, got 'Year'

So I must be missing something.  What?

Here's what I've gotten so far:

Extensions are installed in `..\vendor\beberlei\lib\DoctrineExtensions`

#### app/autoload.php reads:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('DoctrineExtensions', __DIR__.'/../vendor/beberlei/lib/DoctrineExtensions');

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

#### Year function use:

```
class ClientRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function activeStatus($year, $status) {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em
                ->createQuery('select max(Year(ct.contact_date)) CY, 
                c.active
                from ManaClientBundle:Contacts ct
                join ManaClientBundle:Client c on ct.cid = c.id
                group by id')
            ->getResult();

        return $em->createQuery("select CY, count(CY) Status from
                $query where CY = $year and active = '$status'")
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try YEAR instead of Year?

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that the error message says `found YEAR`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you registered the YEAR function to the Doctrine configuration?

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getConfiguration()->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
```

Comment: Adding this line to the function where Year is used results in `Class 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year' not found`.  This error also occurs if I bootleg the function into my bundle and register it in config.yml.

Comment: Are you sure you have got your autoloading setup right? I have installed with composer and the path is `vendor/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/lib/DoctrineExtensions`. Mind the extra `DoctrineExtensions` in my path. If you installed via composer there is no need to add the doctrineExtensions to the autoloader manually, because it already provides psr-0 configuration in composer.json

Comment: I'll back everything out and try that method; I'd done the installation manually.  Not sure exactly how the composer installation is supposed to go, but now's a good time to try.

Comment: OK - I don't know how to use the instructions regarding the DoctrineExtensions composer.json.  I assume that it somehow gets rolled into the symfony composer.json, but tacking the whole thing to the end is not it!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Normally you create a composer.json in the root of your project and setup all your project depencies there. There are lots of tutorials how to do this. If you've done this you just `cd` to your project root and call `composer install` from the command line. Composer downloads all packages and place them in the `vendor` map and sets up alle the autoloading for you. I'm not a symfony user but it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the default symfony composer.json be replaced by the DoctrineExtensions composer.json then run `composer install`? Or modify the existing composer.json?  If the latter, then I'm not sure how best to do that.  If the former (just replace) then I'll see how that works.

Comment: No not replace. Just at the doctrineExtensions as a requirement to the existing composer.json. Like this: `"require": { "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions" : "*" }`, then run `composer update`

Comment: Replacing composer.json is not the answer!  It drops all the other vendor contents!  So I remain confused.  And I will reinstall symfony vendors.Again. ARRGGHH

Comment: My mistakes: 1 - initially modified composer as required but used `composer install` instead of `composer update`; 2 - manually installed extensions but placed them incorrectly.  Spiraled out of control from there.  Now on the air! Thanks immensely for comments and patience.

Comment: Now you know a lot more about composer so that is a positive thing ;). Glad I could be of good help.